# Redefining $f(x,y) = x \cdot y \cdot \sin(1/x)\cdot \sin(1/y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, analytic-continuation

I'm analysing this function from my calculus class:

> $$f(x,y) = x \cdot y \cdot \sin(1/x)\cdot \sin(1/y)$$

I want to know if it's possible to redefine this function to all of $\Bbb R^2$ so it's continuous.

Will it suffice to make it equal to 0 along both axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that
$$\forall X\neq 0  \;\;\;|X\sin (\frac 1X)|\leq |X|$$
we get
$$\lim_0 X\sin (\frac 1X)=0$$

thus, to be continuous at $\mathbb R^2$,
Put $f (x,y)=0$ if $xy=0$ and this is what you said.